# Issue with SQL involving JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables with similar layout, involving INCOME and EXPENSES.
The `id` column is a customer ID.

I need a result of customer TOTAL AMOUNT, summing up income and expenses.

```
Table: Income
| id | amountIN|
+--------------+
| 1  |  a      |  
| 2  |  b      |  
| 3  |  c      |  
| 4  |  d      |  

Table: Expenses
| id | amountOUT|
+---------------+
| 1  |  -x      |   
| 4  |  -z      |
```

My problem is that some customers only have expenses and others just income... so cannot know in advance id I need to do a `LEFT or RIGHT JOIN.`

In the example above an RIGHT JOIN  could do the trick, but if the situation is inverted (more customers on the Expenses table) it doesn't work.

```
Expected Result
    | id | TotalAmount|
    +--------------+
    | 1  |  a - x  |  
    | 2  |  b      |  
    | 3  |  c      |  
    | 4  |  d - z  |
```

Any help?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a trivial statement involving aggregate functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select id, SUM(Amount)
from
(
    select id, amountin as Amount
    from Income
    union all
    select id, amountout as Amount
    from Expense
) a
group by id
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe a full join will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this as a union. Do that in your subquery then sum on it.

For instance:

```
select id, sum(amt) from
(
  select i.id, i.amountIN as amt from Income i
  union all
  select e.id, e.amountOUT as amt from Expenses e
)
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really have another table like client :

```
Table: Client
| id | 
+----+
| 1  |  
| 2  |   
| 3  |  
| 4  |
```

So you could do something like that

```
SELECT Client.ID,  COALESCE(Income.AmountIN, 0) - COALESCE(Expenses.AmountOUT, 0)
FROM Client c
LEFT JOIN Income i ON i.ID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN Expense e ON e.ID = c.ID
```

Will be less complicated and i'm sure it will come handy another time :)